# Get SQL query from LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a query which I am passing `byte[]` as a parameter. I am trying to get the SQL query out of it and run that query in management studio to debug. How can I extract the SQL statement from it?

```
 committeeMember =
           db.Committee_Member.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Customer_Number == activity.Contact.Number
           && x.Position_Start_Date.Value.Year == activity.EndDate
           && x.Committee_Id == activity.Committee.Id && x.Cancelled != 1);
```

Comment: LinqPad would also allow you to see the SQL and run the SQL directly

Comment: For Entity Framework Core => https://stackoverflow.com/a/44180537/2736742

Answer (score 89):

In debugger hover mouse over `commiteeMember` variable - it will show generated SQL query:

[image]

This is what `ToString()` returns for query. You can get same generated SQL query manually by calling ToString:

```
string sql = committeeMember.ToString();
```

This overridden method internally calls [`ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) which returns commands that will run on data source.

---

Also you can use SQL Profiler or Entity Framework Profiler to see which SQL query was executed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: SQL Profiler or Entity Framework Profiler needs run on SQL server machine or my local machine?

Comment: @James123 you can run both on local machine

Comment: Never heard of the Entity Framework Profiler before. Do you have any links to it?

Comment: For those using **Entity Framework 6** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20751723/2218697), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 16):

Incidentally, LINQ to SQL is not entity framework.  If the former, you can set [`[yourDataContext].Log = Console.Out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [some other stream writer](https://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers)) and get the query.

In the query you have, consider writing it as follows to be able to do the `ToString` trick:

```
var committeeMemberQuery =
           db.Committee_Member.*WHERE*
           (x => 
              x.Customer_Number == activity.Contact.Number
                 && x.Position_Start_Date.Value.Year == activity.EndDate
                 && x.Committee_Id == activity.Committee.Id && x.Cancelled != 1
           );

var committeeMember = committeeMemberQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you can do `committeeMemberQuery.ToString()` however you will not get parameter info (you will with [`DataContext.Log = Console.Out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110).aspx) but again, that's not Entity Framework, it's LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I added a link to some other implementations. IMO, the "other streamwriter" option is better than the highest voted answer, because that option allows you to see the sql generated for insert/update operations that get generated when calling `DataContext.SubmitChanges`.

Comment: [yourDataContext].Database.Log = <streamwriter>, if you are using DbContext.

Comment: EF 6 has this: public Action<string> Log { get; set; }

Comment: Why are there asterisks around "WHERE"? That's super confusing

Comment: I'm emphasizing that instead of putting the predicate inside the `FirstOrDefault` call, it's been pulled out into a `Where` call.  There's no way to add additional formatting to code, AFAICT

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for anyone using VS2022:
In debug mode...

Step 1: Set a breakpoint at the statement that comes after the query.

Step 2: When your debug mode hits the breakpoint, hover over the variable which the query inserts values to. A gray box will show up with the object data. You can click the little triangle for more options.

Step 3: Look at the dropdown for Debug view and you can simply just view the query.

That's it!
You can copy and paste that query into SSMS and run it on your database to see what the result should be, just be sure to refresh your database first if you are editing data in your test or method when you hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-display-linq-to-sql-commands for another approach to extract SQL command from linq.

More precisely, the following snippet shows the use case

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");

var q =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

DbCommand dc = db.GetCommand(q);

Console.WriteLine("\nCommand Text: \n{0}",dc.CommandText);
Console.WriteLine("\nCommand Type: {0}",dc.CommandType);
Console.WriteLine("\nConnection: {0}",dc.Connection);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Gives an ouput

```
Command Text:  
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactT  
itle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[Coun  
try], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]  
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]  
WHERE [t0].[City] = @p0  

Command Type: Text  

Connection: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```