# ADO.NET see query that will be sent to SQL server before submitting changes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

Lets say I have the code

```
var Db = new MyEntities();

Random r = new Random();

// select a random customer out of the first 5
var customer = Db.Customers.OrderBy(c=>c.Id).Skip(r.Next(0, 5)).Take(1); 

foreach (var c in customer)
{
    c.WonPrice = true;
}


// How can I see here before saving the changes in order to see
// the query that will be sent to SQL server?
Db.SaveChanges();
```

When SaveChanges() is called how can I see in code the SQL statement that is generated?

Comment: May be this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18237349/961113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is LINQ-to-SQL, then you can attach a `TextWriter` to `Db.Log`: then everything you do via `Db` will be recorded in there. Alternatively, you could use a tool like [mini-profiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/) and just give `MyEntities` a wrapped connection, i.e.

```
public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection()
{
    // A SqlConnection, SqliteConnection ... or whatever
    var cnn = CreateRealConnection();

    // wrap the connection with a profiling connection that tracks timings 
    return new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(cnn,
                                                MiniProfiler.Current);
}

...
using(var Db = new MyEntities(GetOpenConnection()))
{
    ...
}
```