# Linq Any always returns true

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have used Linq to Entities for many years, but this is the first time I'm facing this problem. I have **Tips** and **Items** tables, which each tip can have many items.I have only 3 items in the database. when editing an Item, I want to make sure that **GivenId** field is unique for items in having the same Tip.  I use this:

```
    Item item =db.Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (item != null)
    {
         if (db.Items
               .Any(x => x.GivenId == newGivenId && 
                         x.Id != item.Id && 
                         x.TipId == item.TipId))
         {
              //newGivenId is either different or if it is the same, 
              //it belongs to the same item
         } 
         else
         {
            //newGivenId already exists for an Item in the same tip
         }
   }
```

but

```
    db.Items
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GivenId == newGivenId && 
                            x.Id != item.Id &&  
                            x.TipId == item.TipId);
```

returns `null` as expected.

I know that I can use it like:

```
Item it = db.Items
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GivenId == newGivenId && 
                                 x.Id != item.Id && 
                                 x.TipId == item.TipId);

    if(it==null) 
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

But I just want to find what is wrong with `Any`.

P.S.: All `Id`s (3 of them) are `typeof(int)`

**EDIT:**

this is the generated sql Query:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p__linq__1 AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @p__linq__2 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @p__linq__0 = NULL;
SET @p__linq__1 = NULL;
SET @p__linq__2 = NULL;

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[GivenId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Id] <> @p__linq__1) AND (([Extent1].[TipId] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Extent1].[TipId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

**EF Generated classes:**

```
public partial class Item
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Item()
    {
        this.Parts = new HashSet<Part>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TipId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GivenId { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Carve { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Mina { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Tip Tip { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tip
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tip()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModelId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, can you open the SQL profiler to see what query it ends up sending for the `Any` query?

Comment: Log the generated SQL of EF and show us what it is please.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli How do I get sql of `.Any`?

Comment: I don't know how to get it when using method chaining

Comment: Log the SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework/20751723#20751723 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237312/get-sql-query-from-linq-to-sql

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I managed to get the generated sql. it sets `NULL` for the vars where they should be the values of GivenId, Id and TipId

Comment: Please add the classes code. I can't remember ever having seen EF declare variables as `SQL_VARIANT`. I wonder what makes EF do that.

Comment: in the debugger it shows no variables, but when I click on it, it opens a .sql file with the above code

Comment: @GertArnold I added the classes

Comment: OK, your SQL isn't a 1:1 copy of EF's logging. It's your own variable declaration.

Comment: You could try adding your EF DLL to LINQPad and use it to see the generated SQL for the expressions.

Comment: The Any() will be true if the Given ID exists on another item /w the same Tip ID. From your title you're expecting False and getting True? The comments in your If and Else look to be backwards, and opposite to the if/else conditions for the FirstOrDefault() 2nd example. I.e. the "true" condition for the .Any() would be equivalent to (it != null) for the FirstOrDefault().