# Get generated sql by EF6 on method chaining

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

A simple search on getting generated SQL by EF6 returns lots of results, even many in Stackoverflow. but none of them has suggested any ways when method chaining is used.

For example([How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)):

```
IQueryable query = from x in appEntities
             where x.id = 32
             select x;

var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

but I want to get the generated sql query if it was used like:

```
appEntities.x.Where(x.id==32);
```

Comment: You can get it from your dbms

Comment: If you're using SQL Server you can see it in SQL Profiler.

Comment: I'm using a LocalDB

Comment: You want to check something or will use that sql string somehow?

Comment: I'm facing a very funny problem with a `.Any` method: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643128/linq-any-always-returns-true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643128/linq-any-always-returns-true). I'm trying to see what sql query it runs that it returns a wrong value.

Comment: `appEntities` doesn't have a property `x`. Please ask a clear question.

Comment: @GertArnold appEntities is a Context, x is a table and has a property named id (x.Id)

Comment: Then you can't do `from x in appEntities where ...`. It really doesn't help to use pseudo code in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[Diagnostic/Profiling Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx)**

> Debug -> Windows -> Show Diagnostic Tools ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

inside Visual Studio, then, while debugging, go to Events tab and click on ADO.NET event (or just hover), which will contain the actual sql string queried to DB.

Or you can add this line

```
dbContext.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

before your queries and it will print out your queries inside Output -> Debug.

Or store inside some string if you prefer:

```
//TODO: Remove after checking
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
dbContext.Database.Log = s => log.Append(s);
```

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani where it returns null? It supposed to print out log inside Output tab after your query will be executed.

Comment: You know, `appEntities` is an `ObjectContext`.

Comment: I changed your code to assign the value to a string instead of printing it.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Also an option.