# Got error, "Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply" only on some servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

We updated Entity Framework to 6.1.3, since then on some servers (sadly the ones that run the unit tests), we get now the exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

on some EF queries that aren't that deep nested.

When we changed EF versions we made other changes, but none of these seem to have influenced the unit tests. The service that uses these queries wasn't changed at all.

I didn't find any condition in the environment for this exception, and I kinda can't believe it happens because of the EF update. Are there more influences that could cause this exception?

Edit: I just extracted the query and ran it on one of the failing servers, which is working funnily enough. So I guess it has to be EF?

Comment: What did you update from? What does you SQL statement look like?

Comment: Does all your sql server has exactly the same version ? use `Select @@Version` to check the version.

Comment: Updated the Question, or is it still relevant, which Statement / SQL Version  it is?

Comment: We had the same issue and it was fixed by applying update on SQL Server. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/805659/sql-statement-is-nested-too-deeply

Comment: Can you probably tell me from which version to which version you updated? This would help me a lot.

Comment: I don't remember but it seems that it have been corrected with SQL Server 2012 SP2 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2958429) and SQL Server 2014 SP1 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058865)

Comment: Many thanks, I will update one Build-Server to the same Version I have locally and check if this causes the Problem. It's quite strange nobody else  has this problems.

Comment: Hey Cyril, worked perfectly, thanks. If you mark your Comment as answer, I will mark it.
Interesting enough, it seems like a Combination of SQL and Entity Framework.

Comment: **Related post** - [Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14163390/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

This error message is generated by *SQL Server*. It indicates that a SQL query
can't be analyzed because it is too complex. The new version of *Entity Framework* you used may have a different optimizer that will generate a more nested SQL query than before, this is why you have this error message now.

This error message may also happens on some version of SQL Server. If your SQL Servers don't have the same version, it could explain why you reproduce it only on some configuration. You can find more information on this behavior in this connect bug : [SQL statement is nested too deeply](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/805659/sql-statement-is-nested-too-deeply)

This issue has been fixed with [SQL Server 2012 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2958429) and [SQL Server 2014 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058865)